# How do I insert a lenghthier list in my buffer with elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I do C-u M-: (to insert the result of a lisp statement into the buffer) and I then do something like:

```
(progn (setq x 0 l '()) (while(< x 30) (push (random 99) l) (incf x 1)) (nreverse l))
```

I get:

```
(89 29 27 23 56 88 37 11 33 20 98 95 ...)
```

With trailing ellipsis. What's a way around this? Something like buffer-insert across the resulting list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
(setq eval-expression-print-length nil)
```

in .emacs

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`(insert (pp (loop repeat 30 collect (random 99))))`

May need `(require 'cl)` first.

Comment: +1 for `pp` which I'd never noticed. I gather it's a safe replacement for `prin1` (or `pp-to-string` for `prin1-to-string`), but with nicer formatting for human readability (based on `C-h i g (elisp) Output Functions`.)